# Can we chnage field type in the existing collection of database mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb database for my application and its being 1 year that I'm saving my records in the database. I have `stream` field type of string but now my requirement is change that it will be a array so can I change my all existing records `stream` field string to array using mongodb query or it will be a manually process that I need to perform on it. I'm giving a collection documents below

Collection name  :- `courses`

```
{
   "_id":"object_id",
   "name":"abc",
   "stream":"stream1"
}
{
   "_id":"object_id",
   "name":"abc1",
   "stream":"stream1"
}
{
   "_id":"object_id",
   "name":"ab2c2",
   "stream":"stream1"
}
....
```

The thing that I want is change existing `stream` type of string with slice(array)`[]` as below

Collection name  :- `courses`

```
{
   "_id":"object_id",
   "name":"abc",
   "stream":[
          "stream1"
    ]
}
{
   "_id":"object_id",
   "name":"abc1",
   "stream":[
          "stream1"
    ]
}
{
   "_id":"object_id",
   "name":"ab2c2",
   "stream":[
         "stream1"
    ]
}
....
```

suggestions and answers are most welcome :)